# How to set shader for Armature object in Cocos2dx

Tags: cocos2d-x

I have 3 questions:

1. I know when I want to set shader for Sprite object by using `spr1->setShaderProgram(glProgram)`. However, I want to set shader for an Armature object. How can I do that?
2. In CCSprite, I can use setBlendFunc, what about in Armature.
3. I read this article http://blog.muditjaju.infiniteeurekas.in/?p=1 and I see the idea to detect collision between 2 sprites. But I want to write a extended function which can detect collision between different object like sprite vs sprite, sprite vs Armature, Amature vs Armature. How can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: what the heck is an Armature?

Comment: @LearnCocos2D: Read this http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/native-cpp/V2.2.2/d1/db8/classcocos2d_1_1extension_1_1_c_c_armature.html

Comment: Ooooh-kay. Gotta love a class reference that doesn't even mention what the class is or does. Something to do with armor? Skeletal animation?

Comment: @LearnCocos2D: So do you have any ideas for my 3 questions?

Comment: Not really, I'm not a -x user. I guess 1 & 2 may not be possible because it looks like this class is performing custom drawing. 3 is probably a polygon intersection issue, depends on whether and how you can get the armature's polygon shape.

Answer (score 0):

Today I met the same situation like you. And luckily I found a solution from someone else. The main point is to write a subclass of Armature, say ShaderArmature, and rendering every bone's every child with a shader ---- in my case, the shader is for graying the armature.

You can create a ShaderArmature object and call its **setgrayState**() to enable graying and **setUsuaState**() to remove graying effect.

1, Add the ShaderArmature.h & ShaderArmature.cpp in the same directory of Armature.h.

> ShaderArmature.h

```
//
//  Created by Wangyq on 2017/8/13.
//
//

#ifndef __SHADERARMATURE_H__
#define __SHADERARMATURE_H__

//
//---------shaderArmature.h
///
#include "cocos2d.h"
//#include "extensions/cocos-ext.h"
#include "cocostudio/CocoStudio.h"
//USING_NS_CC_EXT;
USING_NS_CC;
namespace cocostudio{
class CC_STUDIO_DLL ShaderArmature : public Armature
{
public:
    ShaderArmature();
    virtual ~ShaderArmature();

    bool init(const std::string& name) override;

    static ShaderArmature *create(const std::string& name) ;

    virtual void initShader(bool shaderState);
    //    void setBackgroundNotification();

//    draw(cocos2d::Renderer *renderer, const cocos2d::Mat4 &transform, uint32_t flags)
    virtual void draw(Renderer *renderer, const Mat4 &transform, uint32_t transformUpdated) override;
    //    void listenBackToForeground(Ref *obj);
    void setIceState();
    void setUsuaState();

    void setblurState();
    void setbanishState();
    void setfrozenState();
    void setgrayState();
    void setinvisState();
    void setmirrorState();
    void setpoisonState();
    void setstoneState();
protected:
    std::string _fragSourceFile;
    std::string _vertSourceFile;
    //GLchar * fragSource;
    //GLchar * vertSource;
    GLchar fragSource[2048];
    GLchar vertSource[2048];
    bool bSetShader;
};

}
#endif /* __SHADERARMATURE_H__ */
```

> ShaderArmature.cpp

```
//
//  ShaderArmature.cpp
//  cocos2d_libs
//
//  Created by Wangyq on 2017/8/13.
//
//

#include "ShaderArmature.h"

using namespace cocos2d;


namespace cocostudio {
    ShaderArmature::ShaderArmature(){

    }
    ShaderArmature::~ShaderArmature(){

    }
    bool ShaderArmature::init(const std::string& name)
    {
        return Armature::init(name);
    }
    ShaderArmature *ShaderArmature::create(const std::string& name)
    {
        ShaderArmature *armature = new ShaderArmature;
        if (armature && armature->init(name))
        {
            armature->autorelease();
            return armature;
        }
        else{
            CC_SAFE_DELETE(armature);
            return nullptr;
        }
    }


    void ShaderArmature::initShader(bool shaderState){
        //Traverse every bone to set shader
        for (auto& object : _boneDic)
        {
            if (Bone *bone = dynamic_cast<Bone *>(object.second))
            {
                if (bone == nullptr)
                    continue;

                //-----------------!! IMPORTANT !!-----------------
                //Each bone may have more than one child, like several frames, also need to assign shader to them
                //Without this step, only the first frame will have the shader effect.
                const Vector<DecorativeDisplay*> list = bone->getDisplayManager()->getDecorativeDisplayList();
                for (auto& display : list)
                {
                    Node* node = display->getDisplay();
                    if (node == nullptr)
                        continue;

                    if (shaderState){
                        auto program = new GLProgram();
                        program->initWithByteArrays(vertSource, fragSource);


                        node->setGLProgram(program);

                        program->autorelease();

                        CHECK_GL_ERROR_DEBUG();

                        program->bindAttribLocation(GLProgram::ATTRIBUTE_NAME_POSITION, GLProgram::VERTEX_ATTRIB_POSITION);
                        program->bindAttribLocation(GLProgram::ATTRIBUTE_NAME_COLOR, GLProgram::VERTEX_ATTRIB_COLOR);
                        program->bindAttribLocation(GLProgram::ATTRIBUTE_NAME_TEX_COORD, GLProgram::VERTEX_ATTRIB_TEX_COORDS);

                        CHECK_GL_ERROR_DEBUG();

                        program->link();

                        CHECK_GL_ERROR_DEBUG();

                        program->updateUniforms();

                        CHECK_GL_ERROR_DEBUG();

                    }
                    else{//addNormal shader
                        node->setGLProgram(ShaderCache::getInstance()->getProgram(GLProgram::SHADER_NAME_POSITION_TEXTURE_COLOR_NO_MVP));
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
    void ShaderArmature::draw(Renderer *renderer, const Mat4 &transform, uint32_t flags)
    {
        Armature::draw(renderer, transform, flags);
    }

    void ShaderArmature::setIceState(){
        _fragSourceFile = "shader/IceShader.fsh";
        _vertSourceFile = "shader/IceShader.vsh";
        fragSource = (GLchar*)String::createWithContentsOfFile(
            FileUtils::getInstance()->fullPathForFilename(_fragSourceFile).c_str())->getCString();

        vertSource = (GLchar*)String::createWithContentsOfFile(
            FileUtils::getInstance()->fullPathForFilename(_vertSourceFile).c_str())->getCString();
        initShader(true);
    }

    void ShaderArmature::setUsuaState(){
        initShader(false);
    }

    void ShaderArmature::setblurState(){
        _fragSourceFile = "shader/Blur.fsh";
        _vertSourceFile = "shader/Blur.vsh";
        fragSource = (GLchar*)String::createWithContentsOfFile(
            FileUtils::getInstance()->fullPathForFilename(_fragSourceFile).c_str())->getCString();

        vertSource = (GLchar*)String::createWithContentsOfFile(
            FileUtils::getInstance()->fullPathForFilename(_vertSourceFile).c_str())->getCString();
        initShader(true);
    }

    void ShaderArmature::setbanishState(){
        _fragSourceFile = "shader/BanishShader.fsh";
        _vertSourceFile = "shader/BanishShader.vsh";
        fragSource = (GLchar*)String::createWithContentsOfFile(
            FileUtils::getInstance()->fullPathForFilename(_fragSourceFile).c_str())->getCString();

        vertSource = (GLchar*)String::createWithContentsOfFile(
            FileUtils::getInstance()->fullPathForFilename(_vertSourceFile).c_str())->getCString();
        initShader(true);
    }

    void ShaderArmature::setfrozenState(){
        _fragSourceFile = "shader/FrozenShader.fsh";
        _vertSourceFile = "shader/FrozenShader.vsh";
        fragSource = (GLchar*)String::createWithContentsOfFile(
            FileUtils::getInstance()->fullPathForFilename(_fragSourceFile).c_str())->getCString();

        vertSource = (GLchar*)String::createWithContentsOfFile(
            FileUtils::getInstance()->fullPathForFilename(_vertSourceFile).c_str())->getCString();
        initShader(true);
    }
    void ShaderArmature::setgrayState(){
        _fragSourceFile = "shader/GrayScalingShader.fsh";
        _vertSourceFile = "shader/GrayScalingShader.vsh";
        fragSource = (GLchar*)String::createWithContentsOfFile(
            FileUtils::getInstance()->fullPathForFilename(_fragSourceFile).c_str())->getCString();

        vertSource = (GLchar*)String::createWithContentsOfFile(
            FileUtils::getInstance()->fullPathForFilename(_vertSourceFile).c_str())->getCString();
        initShader(true);
    }
    void ShaderArmature::setinvisState(){
        _fragSourceFile = "shader/InvisibleShader.fsh";
        _vertSourceFile = "shader/InvisibleShader.vsh";
        fragSource = (GLchar*)String::createWithContentsOfFile(
            FileUtils::getInstance()->fullPathForFilename(_fragSourceFile).c_str())->getCString();

        vertSource = (GLchar*)String::createWithContentsOfFile(
            FileUtils::getInstance()->fullPathForFilename(_vertSourceFile).c_str())->getCString();
        initShader(true);
    }
    void ShaderArmature::setmirrorState(){
        _fragSourceFile = "shader/MirrorShader.fsh";
        _vertSourceFile = "shader/MirrorShader.vsh";
        fragSource = (GLchar*)String::createWithContentsOfFile(
            FileUtils::getInstance()->fullPathForFilename(_fragSourceFile).c_str())->getCString();

        vertSource = (GLchar*)String::createWithContentsOfFile(
            FileUtils::getInstance()->fullPathForFilename(_vertSourceFile).c_str())->getCString();
        initShader(true);
    }
    void ShaderArmature::setpoisonState(){
        _fragSourceFile = "shader/PoisonShader.fsh";
        _vertSourceFile = "shader/PoisonShader.vsh";
        fragSource = (GLchar*)String::createWithContentsOfFile(
            FileUtils::getInstance()->fullPathForFilename(_fragSourceFile).c_str())->getCString();

        vertSource = (GLchar*)String::createWithContentsOfFile(
            FileUtils::getInstance()->fullPathForFilename(_vertSourceFile).c_str())->getCString();
        initShader(true);
    }

    void ShaderArmature::setstoneState(){
        _fragSourceFile = "shader/StoneShader.fsh";
        _vertSourceFile = "shader/StoneShader.vsh";
        fragSource = (GLchar*)String::createWithContentsOfFile(
            FileUtils::getInstance()->fullPathForFilename(_fragSourceFile).c_str())->getCString();

        vertSource = (GLchar*)String::createWithContentsOfFile(
            FileUtils::getInstance()->fullPathForFilename(_vertSourceFile).c_str())->getCString();
        initShader(true);
    }
}
```

---

2, For shader files, I put them in the folder "res/shader". Every shader consists of 2 files -- a .vsh file & a .fsh file. Take graying for example:

> GrayScalingShader.fsh

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump float;
#endif

varying vec4 v_fragmentColor;
varying vec2 v_texCoord;
uniform sampler2D u_texture;

void main()
{
    vec4 normalColor = v_fragmentColor * texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoord);

    //float gray = 0.299*0.5*normalColor.r + 0.587*0.5*normalColor.g + 0.114*0.5*normalColor.b;
    //gl_FragColor = vec4(gray*0.8 + normalColor.r*0.2, gray*0.8 + normalColor.g*0.2, gray*0.8 + normalColor.b*0.2, normalColor.a*0.3);
    float gray = dot(normalColor.rgb, vec3(0.299 * 0.5, 0.587 * 0.5, 0.114 * 0.5));
    gl_FragColor = vec4(gray, gray, gray, normalColor.a * 1);
}
```

> GrayScalingShader.vsh

```
attribute vec4 a_position;
attribute vec2 a_texCoord;
attribute vec4 a_color;

#ifdef GL_ES
varying lowp vec4 v_fragmentColor;
varying mediump vec2 v_texCoord;
#else
varying vec4 v_fragmentColor;
varying vec2 v_texCoord;
#endif

void main()
{
    //gl_Position = CC_MVPMatrix * a_position;
    gl_Position = CC_PMatrix * a_position;
    v_fragmentColor = a_color;
    v_texCoord = a_texCoord;
}
```

Hope this would be helpful.